# XSLT : Replace an XML value if this value exists in another node

Tags: xml, xslt

I need you help regarding the following need.

I have this input XML :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multi>
    <batchPartResponse>
        <batchQueryPartResponse>
            <body>
                <ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
                    <ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                        <LocalObjectID>ABC</LocalObjectID>
                        <RemoteObjectID>100828</RemoteObjectID>
                    </ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                </ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
            </body>
        </batchQueryPartResponse>
        <batchQueryPartResponse>
            <body>
                <ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
                    <ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                        <LocalObjectID/>
                        <RemoteObjectID>100666</RemoteObjectID>
                    </ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                </ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
            </body>
        </batchQueryPartResponse>
    </batchPartResponse>
    <root>
        <CustomerPaymentInfo>
            <PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
                <CustomerCode>100828</CustomerCode>
            </PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
        </CustomerPaymentInfo>
        <CustomerPaymentInfo>
            <PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
                <CustomerCode>100666</CustomerCode>
            </PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
        </CustomerPaymentInfo>
    </root>
</multi>
```

What I want to do is : if //PaymentForeCastAndOverDues/CustomerCode = //ObjectIdentifierMapping/RemoteObjectID then replace CustomerCode  by LocalObjectID, and if LocalObjectID is null, then do not replace.

The expected result is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multi>
    <batchPartResponse>
        <batchQueryPartResponse>
            <body>
                <ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
                    <ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                        <LocalObjectID>ABC</LocalObjectID>
                        <RemoteObjectID>100828</RemoteObjectID>
                    </ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                </ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
            </body>
        </batchQueryPartResponse>
        <batchQueryPartResponse>
            <body>
                <ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
                    <ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                        <LocalObjectID/>
                        <RemoteObjectID>100666</RemoteObjectID>
                    </ObjectIdentifierMapping>
                </ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection>
            </body>
        </batchQueryPartResponse>
    </batchPartResponse>
    <root>
        <CustomerPaymentInfo>
            <PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
                <CustomerCode>ABC</CustomerCode>
            </PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
        </CustomerPaymentInfo>
        <CustomerPaymentInfo>
            <PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
                <CustomerCode>100666</CustomerCode>
            </PaymentForeCastAndOverDues>
        </CustomerPaymentInfo>
    </root>
</multi>
```

Can you please share your advice ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My advice is to use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to resolve cross-references. Then, if you run into a problem you cannot overcome, post your code.

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your suggestion it works well. Just one thing I can't do is how to do nothing if the value is empty. ** `<xsl:key name="CustomerKey" match="ObjectIdentifierMappingCollection/ObjectIdentifierMapping" use="RemoteObjectID" /> <xsl:template match="CustomerCode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('CustomerKey', .)/LocalObjectID"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and add your XSLT code there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="CustomerKey" match="ObjectIdentifierMapping" use="RemoteObjectID" /> 

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CustomerCode">
    <xsl:variable name="objID" select="key('CustomerKey', .)/LocalObjectID" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string($objID)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$objID"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. If you want, you can shorten the 2nd template to:

```
<xsl:template match="CustomerCode">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="(key('CustomerKey', .)/LocalObjectID[string(.)] | .)[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Personally, I prefer the longer and more readable version.